# Meteor handlebars {{#if}} turns strings into objects

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

[The bug source code is here](https://github.com/krstffr/meteor-handlebars-bug/tree/master).

Let's say I'm looping over an array in Meteor using an ordinary `{{#each}}` loop. Each array element is a string, and I output the string every step using `{{this}}`. So far so good! If I use a handlebars helper to check `typeof` for `this` I'll get `string`. Sweet! Everything is as it should be.

But if I add an `{{#if something }}`-helper inside the `{{#each}}` (the `something` just returns true and thus keeps going and outputs `{{this}}`) the string will still look good in the HTML, but it is now an `object` in the `typeof` check!

This is super-annoying as all the `(typeof someVarINeedToTest === 'string')` my code might depend on now will return false.

Am I doing something wrong?

Or is this an actual bug?

If so: is it a Meteor-specific or Handlebars-specific bug?

Thanks!

Oh: [the source link again](https://github.com/krstffr/meteor-handlebars-bug/tree/master). Just pull and run `meteor` and look in your browser console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `this` variable is supposed to always be an object in JavaScript so when `someFunction.apply(someContext);` is called in by handlebars, JavaScript turns `someContext` into an object no matter what it started as. See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SyKSE/1/

(In this case, `someFunction` represents the part of your template that's within the `{{#if}}` statement.)

A simple (albeit ugly) workaround would be to just always pass your data in as an object, so

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'array', 'that', 'we\'re', 'looping', 'through'];
```

becomes:

```
[{val: 'this'}, {val: 'is'}, {val: 'an'}, {val: 'array'}, {val: 'that'}, {val: 'we\'re'}, {val: 'looping'}, {val: 'through'}];
```

And then you'd change your template to look at `val` instead of `this`

Comment: Another workaround you can use in the case of comparing strings: _.isEqual(this, stringToCompareAgainst). Note also that Template.currentData() returns a string not an Object